# render child component on return from ajax call in parent in react

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble rendering (and re-rendering) a child component dependent on data in its parent. There is an ajax call in the parent to retrieve the data because the ajax needs to be called from a different child component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        }
        changeAccount(){
            this.updateList(getParameters());
        }
        updateList(args){
            let that = this;
            // here is the ajax call
            ajax({....
                success: function(data){
                    that.setState({items: data})
                }
            })
        }
    render () {
        return (
           <SelectAccount changeAccount={this.changeAccount}/>
           <Table items={this.state.items} getInitialItems={this.changeAccount}/>
        )
    }
}
```

`SelectAccount` is not super important here. It is a component that has selection options to change an account, which calls the ajax method of the parent component. I would like to be able to re-render the `Table` component whenever the data is returned from the server.

The Table component is as such:

```
classTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: this.props.items
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getInitialItems();
    }
    render () {
        let rows = [];
        this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            rows.push(<Row item={item} key={item.key} />)});
        return (
            <div className="table-body">{rows}</div>
        )
    }
```

The caveat here also, is that I would like the table to render first with an empty array, and once it is mounted I would like to call the ajax method in the parent to populate the data. The same ajax call happens when a user changes accounts so I need to bind the `items` in `Parent` to the `items` in `Table` and have it re-rendered.

So, child renders (`Table`), calls the ajax method (`updateList()`) in `Parent` and 'passes' the `items` back down to `Table' where its`items` are updated.

I have tried putting the ajax call in the `Table` component, but that creates its own issues in calling that method from a sibling component.

Looking for suggestions - I'm obviously missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to set `Table`'s state with items from parent, just use a plain property.
When the `Parent`'s state changes, `Table`'s props will be updated and the component re-rendered by React.
Here's a simple example, the Ajax call is replaced by a simple variable set triggered by a click on the button.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
    this.bind()
  }

  bind() {
    this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this)
  }

  updateList(args) {
    // Update state with harcoded list of items
    // this could be easily replaced by an Ajax call
    this.setState({
      items: ['some', 'new', 'stuff']
    })
  }
  
  // Render parent component, pass items list
  // into Table's props
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.updateList}>AJAX</button>
      <Table items={this.state.items} getInitialItems={this.changeAccount} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  // Render table using this.props.items
  // React will handle the component's re-rendering
  // when state of Parent changes
  render () {
    let rows = [];
    this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
      rows.push(<li key={index}>{item}</li>)
                });
      return (
        <div className="table-body">{rows}</div>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I was over engineering it.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, I think you can find your answer here:  http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/

He lists your specific case as "1) Root Component", you need to create the initial items outside your parent control and pass them in as props.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that case 1 is my case. Unfortunately it is not working. Good article, but examples would be nice.

Comment: Modify your question to show how you're using your Parent class.

Comment: What do you mean? It is basically the root component. I am setting the state in the success ajax callback. That needs to then update the Table component.